# How do I use Gather and Scatter functions in MPI using python mpi4py library for matrix multiplication

Tags: mpi, hpc, mpi4py

I was writing the code for Matrix Multiplication in python using mpi4py library and I am stuck on the part where Gather and Scatter functions are used, there is not much documentation regarding how to use it. The only websites I was able to find was [this one which has the Official documentation about the library](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) which is very new and the other one was [this page](https://pythonprogramming.net/mpi-gather-command-mpi4py-python/).

The code I have written so far is

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank=comm.rank
size=comm.size

a = [[12,7,3],
    [4 ,5,6],
    [7 ,8,9]]

b = [[5,8,1],
    [6,7,3],
    [4,5,9]]

res = [[0,0,0],
         [0,0,0],
         [0,0,0]]
aa = [0,0,0]
cc = [0,0,0]
sum = 0

comm.Scatter(a, aa, root = 0)

for r in range(size):
    if rank == r:
        print("[%d] %s" %(rank, aa))         #this was just to check whether the Scattered values are being sent or not

comm.Bcast(b,root = 0)

for i in range(len(a)):
   for j in range(len(b[0])):
       for k in range(len(b)):
            sum = sum + aa[j] * b[j][i]
            cc[i] = sum                      #main calculation


comm.Gather(cc, res, root = 0)               #here it should gather all values from cc to res matrix
if rank == 0:
    for r in res:
        print(r)                            #final printing of the res matrix
```

The error it's showing is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "matrixmultMPI.py", line 22, in <module>
    comm.Scatter(a, aa, root = 0)
  File "mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx", line 740, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Scatter
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 606, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_scatter
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 511, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_cco_recv
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 203, in mpi4py.MPI.message_simple
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 138, in mpi4py.MPI.message_basic
  File "mpi4py/MPI/asbuffer.pxi", line 365, in mpi4py.MPI.getbuffer
  File "mpi4py/MPI/asbuffer.pxi", line 148, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_GetBuffer
  File "mpi4py/MPI/asbuffer.pxi", line 140, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_GetBuffer
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "matrixmultMPI.py", line 22, in <module>
    comm.Scatter(a, aa, root = 0)
  File "mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx", line 740, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Scatter
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 606, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_scatter
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 511, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_cco_recv
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 203, in mpi4py.MPI.message_simple
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 138, in mpi4py.MPI.message_basic
  File "mpi4py/MPI/asbuffer.pxi", line 365, in mpi4py.MPI.getbuffer
  File "mpi4py/MPI/asbuffer.pxi", line 148, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_GetBuffer
  File "mpi4py/MPI/asbuffer.pxi", line 140, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_GetBuffer
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "matrixmultMPI.py", line 22, in <module>
    comm.Scatter(a, aa, root = 0)
  File "mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx", line 740, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Scatter
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 606, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_scatter
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 511, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_cco_recv
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 203, in mpi4py.MPI.message_simple
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 138, in mpi4py.MPI.message_basic
  File "mpi4py/MPI/asbuffer.pxi", line 365, in mpi4py.MPI.getbuffer
  File "mpi4py/MPI/asbuffer.pxi", line 148, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_GetBuffer
  File "mpi4py/MPI/asbuffer.pxi", line 140, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_GetBuffer
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "matrixmultMPI.py", line 22, in <module>
    comm.Scatter(a, aa, root = 0)
  File "mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx", line 740, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Scatter
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 597, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_scatter
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 495, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_cco_send
  File "mpi4py/MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 186, in mpi4py.MPI.message_simple
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: generally speaking, `mpi4py` works best with `numpy` arrays, so unless you have a good reason not to use `numpy`, I suggest you first rewrite your code with it.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet oh, I was not aware about numpy arrays being the best option, but still I wanted to know how Scatter and Gather works in python, in C it's quite easy to work with it

Comment: `Scatter()` works only with a buffer-like objects (such as `numpy` arrays). Here, I guess you can only use `scatter()` (note `S` vs `s`) since you are using python objects.